# How to inject the location of the config.ini file to the variable present in the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a module which refers a config file that contains various parameters used by the module.

I want the user of my module to inject their custom location of the config.ini file and start using various functions present in it.

what I have tried and did not work is call this method  [here][1]

my_module/**init**.py

```
config_file='config.ini'

def set_config_ini_file_full_path(self, config_file: str):
    """ Sets config file. set_config_ini_file_full_path(config_file= full_path_to/config.ini)"""
    self.config_file = config_file

#rest of code uses this config_file for getting config values
```

myscript.py

```
import my_module # this itself enough to throw the config_file doesn't exist error
from my_module import set_config_ini_file_full_path

my_module.config_file='some_location/config.ini'


#or

set_config_ini_file_full_path(my_module , config_file='some_location/config.ini')
```

tried to inject the config location. But it did not work. just import my_module triggers the config_file missing error before even setting in myscript.py

Is there any way to inject the custom location of the users config file to config_file variable of the module?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't put links to off-site source code in your questions, put all code related to in your question in it.

Comment: @martineau Removed. Thanks

Comment: What is `self` in these examples?

Comment: corrected now. I added it to inject modules env so that it modifies the variable on the same environment which other code are running

Comment: @0x5453 used to access instance variables